# HashMap generics

Tags: java, hashmap

What is different between < > & ()  ?
How does this work?

```
HashMap<**String**,**String**> HM= new HashMap<**String**, **String**>();
HashMap HM= new HashMap();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<>` is for generic types and the `()` is for function parameters in java.